# Why geolocator package return different decimal position(Latitude,Longtitude)?

Tags: flutter, geolocation, android-gps, geolocator

My question is about the difference between decimal places when using ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
what I know is that ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is more precise than ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.
Well, when I tried it, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION returns 6 digits after the decimal point in latitude and longitude but ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION returns 16 digits.
I expected the opposite since ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is supposed to be more precise.
am I wrong? Correct me, please.

here's an example of what I get:
latitude / longitude / accuracy
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION XX.468468468468465 / X.6946368516051495 / 2000.0
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION XX.4697797 / X.6927091 / 21.600000381469727

package Version
9.0.2
device:
samsung with android 13

Answer (score 0):

We can't judge the acuracy and precise by the number of decimal places.

The difference between them is:

- `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`: Define the  location by **network provider**. it has accuracy about **100m-500m**
- `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`: are use **Network provider** + **GPS sensor** on the device. It has accuracy about less than **100m**

Comment: Thank you for your, so I'll just go with ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to get a precise location.

Comment: Keep in mind that fine location burns batteries faster.  That's why you have two versions.